# Set jsPlumb Line Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jsplumb

I had made a line using jsPlumb.

```
var jsPlumb_instance = jsPlumb.getInstance();   
var endpointOptions = { 
                anchor:'BottomCenter',
                maxConnections:1,                      
                endpoint:['Rectangle',{width:'0px', height:'0px' }], 
                paintStyle:{fillStyle:'black'},
                connectorStyle : {  lineWidth: '1px' , strokeStyle: 'black' },
                connector : ['Straight'],                   
                setDragAllowedWhenFull:true,                    


};  
div1Endpoint = jsPlumb_instance.addEndpoint(id1, endpointOptions);
div2Endpoint = jsPlumb_instance.addEndpoint(id2, endpointOptions);      

jsPlumb_instance.connect({  
    source:div1Endpoint,
    target:div2Endpoint,
});
```

I want to customize the line by tweaking its pattern. I noticed the line was just solid, like the image below:

[image]

I want to make it dashed or dotted line. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to customize **paintStyle**

```
jsPlumb_instance.connect({  
    source:div1Endpoint,
    target:div2Endpoint,
    paintStyle:{ strokeStyle:"blue", lineWidth:10,dashstyle = '3 3' }
});
```

By the way there are three types of paintStyle's; for source endpoint, target endpoint and connection.

You may like to check here;
https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/paint-styles.html

Here is an example;
http://jsfiddle.net/mokarakaya/gcabyo3h/4/

Comment: Thank you but what does '3 3' represents in your dashstyle value? I could not find it in the documentation link.

Comment: @Eliyyahu  I have created an example. I hope it helps;
http://jsfiddle.net/mokarakaya/gcabyo3h/4/

Comment: '3 3' means in connection line 3 width of line is followed by 3 width of blank and so on.